# Visual Studio 2013 fails to build from network share

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project on a Mac which I'm trying to build, over a network share, on a PC.

However Visual Studio reports:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database
>   'X:\XYZ\Builds\VisualStudio2013\Debug\XYZ.pdb'; check for insufficient
>   disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege

Yet:

```
>dir XYZ.pdb
 Directory of X:\XYZ\Builds\VisualStudio2013\Debug
20/04/2015  17:32         9,456,640 XYZ.pdb
               0 Dir(s)  15,825,752,064 bytes free
```

There it is, created by VisualStudio a second ago, so it must have write permissions and there's plenty of disk space.  I've had a poke around the permissions and I can't see what's wrong.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?  It'd be very handy!

EDIT: I've upgraded SMB on the mac to the latest version and that's not helped either!

Comment: Do you have the correct security permissions?

Comment: Yes.  Visual Studio itself created the file it's complaining it can't write to.  I can read and write from that folder (which is shared using Samba from the Mac).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Try adding a `veto oplock files` setting to your smb.conf that specifies the .pdb file of your VS solution per the instructions [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/locking.html#id2616903).

---

One possibility is that the supposed lack of permissions is due to Visual Studio itself attempting to open the file multiple times. I've seen weird issues like this with Visual Studio when building on a network share, even when the network share was running on a Windows server. However, on Windows Server, there's a timeout in such scenarios (default of 35 seconds) after which it would allow the second file handle to open and then continue about its business. I ended up having to watch Wireshark traces of the SMB traffic to figure out what was going on there.

IIRC, the exchange went something like:

1. VS opens a handle to the .pdb. By default, it receives exclusive access since it's the only handle open to the file at the time.
2. VS attempts to open a second handle to the .pdb, but it's currently open for exclusive access already.
3. The SMB server sends a message to ask the client holding the first handle (which also happens to be VS) whether it's ok to switch the handle into shared access mode.
4. VS is unable to respond to the server's request because it's blocked waiting on a response from the server to its request to open the second handle.
5. A timeout expires on the SMB server, after which it forcibly switches the handle into shared mode. This timeout is enabled by default on Windows SMB/CIFS servers.
6. The SMB server now allows the second file handle to open and VS continues along its merry way.

This behavior is called 'opportunistic locking' and Microsoft has a document on how to configure it on Windows file servers [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/296264). `OplockBreakWait` is the amount of time (in seconds) that the server will wait for a client to respond to an oplock break request.

However, it sounds like perhaps the oplock break request timeout might not be happening on your samba implementation. There's a document [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/locking.html#id2616903) in samba's documentation on how to configure oplocks in samba. It mentions an option that can be specified in `smb.conf` called `veto oplock files` that allows you to specify certain files for which oplocking will be disabled. **You could try adding your .pdb to the `veto oplock files` setting in your `smb.conf` to see if this fixes your problem.**

Incidentally, the samba document linked above mentions that its default oplock break wait time is 0, which I would assume disables the timeout, resulting in the behavior you're seeing. Unfortunately, the link in that document to the actual documentation for the `oplock break wait time` option is broken, so I can't confirm for sure that that's what it does. According to the linked samba documentation, `"Samba recommends: “Do not change this parameter unless you have read and understood the Samba oplock code,”"` so you're probably better off attempting to modify `veto oplock files` than `oplock break wait time` unless reading the source code of samba is your idea of fun. :)

Comment: Sadly, and that was an awesome response, it hasn't fixed it.  There are a bunch of these in the logs but I dont' think they are related to the problem: 11/05/2015 16:56:49.603 smbd[36720]: File system does not support 0X40000, file attrs
11/05/2015 16:56:49.603 smbd[36720]: File system does not support 0X0 time attrs
11/05/2015 16:56:49.603 smbd[36720]: File system does not support 0X0, size attrs

Comment: Ah - hang on - smb problem.  I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Okay - so it's a great answer - I'll give you the bonus.  There's now a (potentially unresolvable) bug in smb on the mac causing it to core dump so I still need to test it!

Comment: @JCx Sorry to hear you're still having problems. I haven't used samba on OS X in several years, but back when I did have to use it, it was a real mess. For a while, we literally had to reboot the server every day or two because, if we didn't, the server would literally kernel panic after about 2-3 days of uptime on average.

Comment: I've given up entirely and moved to using Visual Studio under Parallels which works.  But it was a great answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I know that the answer for this question was already done, But the accepted answer doesn't work in my case. 
Here is the solution of my problem:
When scale of the project grows and size of the **".pdb"** file exceed 300MB, the error accrued.
I change debugging info properties in my project and successfully compile it.
You just need to change "Debug information format" in your project to **"C7 compatible (/Z7)"** in the following path.

> Configuration properties >> C/C++ >> General >> Debug Information
>   Format

Comment: This is for a completely different problem. It may result in the same error message, but that doesn't make your answer relevant here. It's good that you share your answer, it may definitely help others, but can you find a more relevant question to post it as an answer to?

Comment: @hvd : you are right when you say that the answer is not fully relevant to the question, But I put my answer here because the error message is same and many other people (like me at last week) that searching for the solution of that error, will come to this post. So I decide to share my answer for those people, just to help them.